# Como abrir una pagina html desde javascript pasandoles parametros

Tags: javascript, html, html5

estoy buscando de abrir una pagina nueva, pero que al abrirla se le pase un parametro. Ejemplo:

fichero A:

```
<html>
 .....
<script>
  var user="mi_nombre_de_usuario";
 location.href="/pagina_b"+user;

</scritp>
.....
 </html>
```

Hasta el momento he intentado varias cosas pero no logro que abra la "pagina_b" y que ademas obtenga un parametro.De momento tengo este codigo que encontre en internet.

```
function pasarVariables(pagina, nombres) {
pagina +="?";
nomVec = nombres.split(",");
for (i=0; i<nomVec.length; i++)
pagina += nomVec[i] + "=" + escape(eval(nomVec[i]))+"&";
pagina = pagina.substring(0,pagina.length-1);
location.href=pagina;
}
//location.href="../prueba?hola" ; 
pasarVariables("../prueba",username);
}
```

Cualquier sugerencia la agradeceria.

Comment: `location.href="pagina_b?user=" + user;`

Comment: Hola gracias, pero no lo acepta, ya que lo que hace es buscar el fichero con el nombre "pagina_b?user=....."

Comment: Si lo que dice Ruben no funciona prueba document.location="/pagina?user=valor" O para una ventana nueva Window.open("/pagina.html?user=valor")

Answer (score 1):

En la linea 2 del segundo código prueba a poner esto:

`pagina +="/?";`

La url se vería más o menos así:

`pagina_b/?user=Name`

**No te olvides de poner la barra lateral**